# itext html to pdf without embedding fonts

Tags: pdf, itext7

I'm following this guide in [Chapter 6](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-6-using-fonts-pdfhtml) of [iText 7: Converting HTML to PDF with pdfHTML](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml) on adding extra fonts:

```
public static final String FONT = "src/main/resources/fonts/cardo/Cardo-Regular.ttf";
public void createPdf(String src, String font, String dest) throws IOException {
    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
    FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);
    FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(font);
    fontProvider.addFont(fontProgram, "Winansi");
    properties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);
    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(src), new File(dest), properties);
}
```

While it's working as expected and embedding subsets of the fonts being used, I'm wondering if there is a way for the resulting PDF document to **not** embed the fonts at all. This is possible when creating `BaseFont` instances and setting the `embedded` property to `false` and using them to build various PDF building blocks. What I'm looking for is this same behavior when using the  `HtmlConverter.convertToPdf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should normally do is override `FontProvider`:

```
FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false) {
    @Override
    public boolean getDefaultEmbeddingFlag() {
        return false;
    }
};
```

However, the problem is that at the moment this font provider would be overwritten by pdfHTML further into the pipeline in `ProcessorContext#reset`.

While this issue is not fixed in iText you can build a custom version of pdfHTML for your needs. The repo is located at https://github.com/itext/i7j-pdfhtml and you are interested in [this](https://github.com/itext/i7j-pdfhtml/blob/e624c4690401f7b48d5b59b1814a74e896d7b0d9/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/html2pdf/attach/ProcessorContext.java#L417) line. Just replace it with the overload as above and build the jar.

**UPD** The fix is available starting from **pdfHTML 2.1.3**. From that version on you can use custom font providers freely.

Comment: Thanks - this helped. I'm actually unsure as to why this line that resets the `FontProvider` even exists at all (without diving into the html2pdf code). By simply commenting it out, our PDF creation process actually re-uses the fonts after each `HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements()` call, significantly reducing the number of embedded font subsets which solves the file size issue we were having in the first place.

Comment: @StevenHovland I just want to tell you that the issue has been fixed and now it's possible to use custom font providers. 

Unfortunately the fix will not be present in the next release (which is scheduled to take place at the end of January), but it can be found at iText's github and iText's Artifactory.

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk Thanks for the update. I'll check it out